# Go Down In A Notebook

Tags: phrasal-verbs, figurative-language

I have a question about the usage of "*go down*" in this [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/go-down?q=go+down):

> It all ***goes down*** in her notebook.

I was thinking this sense of "*go down*" should be used with "*in history*", not "*in a notebook*".  Do native speakers think that the example sentence is weird?

Comment: I think your question is weirder than the sentence in the dictionary. Why on earth would _go down_ be limited in use to _go down in history_?

Answer (score 1):

From the site you provided a link to in your question:

> go down (in something) to be written in something; to be recorded or remembered in something

This use of *go down* does not have to be paired with *(in) history*. Native speakers would not find your example sentence (or similar sentences that use *go down* in the same way) weird.

Answer (score 1):

*go down in history as* is an idiomatic phrase which is used in the certain context, of course, this phrase is very popular. *go down in her notebook* is another phrase which is used in another context, and has a different meaning.

*go down in* has many words which can go after. Some examples from the BNC (British National Corpus):

> go down in posterity
>
> go down in value
>
> go down in television
>
> go down in summer
>
> go down in London
>
> go down in size
>
> go down in colour
>
> Which car did Nigel go down in on the Thursday?

Comment: You forgot _go down in flames_.

Answer (score 1):

I think this "It all goes down in her notebook" is modelled after "to put something down on paper".

Answer (score 0):

The phrase **go down** has many uses where **go** is a **shortened form** of an expression to replace **several different verbs**, but the action always involves **movement** and **down** can be used metaphorically to **show direction**

In your example

> It all **goes down** in her notebook.

means things are **written down** in a notebook

> Let me grab a pen so I can make a note and **write that down**

usually the writing surface is **below** the person writing

It means to **travel south**

> We are **going down** to the Caribbean to catch some sun.
>   I'll be **going down** to London from Edinburgh next week.

It means to **descend**

> **Go down** to the basement, the wine cellar is on the right
>   We'll **go down** the mountain before it gets dark *(skiing)*

It means to **drink** or **eat**

> This cold beer really **goes down** nicely after a long day
>   That Muscadet **goes down** well with seafood
>   The greasy sausages **went down** easily

It means to **travel further**

> Just **go down** the road and you'll see their house
>   If you **go down** this path you'll see the tree

It means to be **noted**

> Rudolf the red nose reindeer, you'll **go down** in history

It is a type of **sex**

> She likes it when he **goes down** on her

It can also mean how something is **received**

> The play is **going down** well, the critics like it
>   The joke **went down** like a lead balloon

**Go down** is very useful indeed.

**Go down** may or may not be the opposite of **come down**

> When you **go down** from the top of the mountain, the people in the valley will see you **coming down**

**come down** can also mean a **dampening of spirits**

> Turning on the lights during the dance was a real **come down**
>   Running out of beer was a real **come down** at the party last night

For directions **go down** and **come up** are opposites

> **Go down** to the first floor, then **come** *(back)* **up** to the fourth floor

**Come up** can also mean **to appear quickly**

> His illness **came up** all of a sudden